# Filtering django model using date

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to filter some data from models using the date. I see some posts that speaks about ranges but I just want to see for example the rows of my table from the 22/04/2020, in other words, just one day.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date), I understood that I have to do the following,

```
import datetime

prueba = DevData.objects.order_by('-data_timestamp').filter(data_timestamp=datetime.date(2020, 4, 22))
prueba = loads(serializers.serialize('json', prueba))
for p in prueba:
    print(p)
```

But appears the following warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField DevData.data_timestamp received a naive datetime (2020-04-22 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.

And the list appears empty. I think the problem is that is just filtering using `2020-04-22 00:00:00` and not all the day. How can I fix this?

Between two dates is working but just one day I don't know how to do it.

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2020, 4, 22)
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 4, 23)
prueba = DevData.objects.order_by('-data_timestamp').filter(data_timestamp__range= (start_date,end_date))
```

*PD: I have info rows in this day.*

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`__date`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) to filter on the date of the timestamp:

```
import datetime

prueba = DevData.objects.order_by(
    '-data_timestamp'
).filter(
    data_timestamp__date=datetime.date(2020, 4, 22)
)
```

Comment: Wow was easy (ashamed)... Thank you very much!